# JavaScript Performance – Remove Pseudo DOM Items

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, svg, memory

In order to calculate paths I am creating multiple SVG Elements in the background like so:

```
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
```

The problem is that this is happening in a loop with an unforeseeable amount of paths being created. The elements are NOT appended to the body. My question is will all these pseudo elements impact performance/memory? Or will they be garbage collected?

If not what is the best technique to remove the elements from the document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector collects all of the variables that cannot be reached anymore, so either your code runs on top-level, which means the variables will be attached to `window`, thus not garbage collectable, or your code runs in a `function`, in that case they will be collected when the `function` ends if there is not some closure inside, keeping a reference on them, like in the following example:

```
function foo() {
    var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    return function() {
        // Do something with path;
    }
}

var bar = foo();
```

In that case, `path` will live as long as `bar` does, because it has a reference on the inner anonymous `function`, which has a reference on `path`.

Comment: Okay thanks! They run in a function so I have nothing to worry about!